# CORS express js dont save a cookie

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cookies, cross-domain

I read a lot of questions like this but no one is usefull for me.
I have a MERN app. I use Heroku to deploy. In my local environent everithing works but in heroku the login crash. I use Cookies. and try every posible configuration.

Please help.

This is my login server:

```
 

    login: async (req, res) => {
            try {
                const { email, password } = req.body;
                const user = await Users.findOne({ email })
                //console.log(user)
                if (!user) return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Usuario inexistente" })
    
                const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
                if (!isMatch) return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Clave erronea" })
    
                //If login success, craete access Token and refresh
                const accesstoken = createAccessToken({ id: user._id })
                const refreshtoken = createRefreshToken({ id: user._id })
    
                //console.log(refreshtoken)
                res.cookie('refreshtoken', refreshtoken, {
                    sameSite: 'strict',
                    httpOnly: true,
                    path: '/user/refresh_token',
                    maxAge: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 //7days
                })
                res.json({ accesstoken })
    
            } catch (err) {
                return res.status(500).json({ msg: err.message })
            }
        },
```

Here server conf.

```
    //MIDDELEWARES
    app.use(express.json())
    app.use(cookieParser())
    //app.use(cors())
    /*app.use(cors({
        credentials: true,
        origin: 'https://gabymanualidades.herokuapp.com/'
      }))*/
    app.use(cors({origin: 'https://*****.herokuapp.com', methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'OPTIONS', 'HEAD'], credentials: true, headers: 'Authorization, X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Request-Method' }))
    app.use(fileUpload({
        useTempFiles: true
    }))
```

And client:

```
    const loginSubmit = async e => {
            e.preventDefault()
            try {
                //await axios.post('/user/login', { ...user })
                const res=await axios.post('/user/login', { ...user }, {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    withCredentials: true,
                    baseURL: "*****.herokuapp.com"
                })
    
                console.log(res)
    
                localStorage.setItem('firstLogin', true)
    
                //window.location.href = "/products";
            } catch (err) {
                alert(err.response.data.msg)
            }
        }
```

Thak you very much!

---

Screenshot:

[image]

It is as if I logged in without saving the cookie since then I can't get it again here:

```
    useEffect(() => {
            const firstLogin = localStorage.getItem('firstLogin')
            if (firstLogin) refreshToken()
        }, [])
    
        const refreshToken = async () => {
            try {
                console.log("aca problema")
                const res = await axios.get('/user/refresh_token', {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    withCredentials: true,
                    baseURL: "https://young-wildwood-03509.herokuapp.com/"
                })
                setToken(res.data.accesstoken)
                setTimeout(() => {
                    refreshToken()
                }, 10 * 60 * 1000)
                
            } catch (err) {
                alert(err.response.data.msg)
            }
        }
```

Server:

```
    refreshToken: (req, res) => {
            try {
                //console.log(req.cookies)
                const rf_token = req.cookies.refreshtoken;
                if (!rf_token) return res.status(401).json({ msg: "Plase Login or registeer" })
    
    
                jwt.verify(rf_token, process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET, (err, user) => {
                    if (err) return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Plase Login or registerr" })
                    const accesstoken = createAccessToken({ id: user.id })
                    //res.json({user, accesstoken})
                    console.log({ accesstoken })
                    res.json({ accesstoken })
                })
    
                //res.json({ rf_token })
            } catch (err) {
                return res.status(500).json({ msg: err.message })
            }
    
        },
```

Comment: Can you please add an error screenshot?

Comment: I just updated it to attach the capture and more code data. Thank you!